# Store SP 2013 Work Flow Audit Report in a List or Column in the same List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, visual-studio, auditing

Has anyone came across any tutorials or links on how to store WF audit reports to a list or in the same list but on a column? I have scoured the net and I am not having any luck in getting the information that I need to begin. What I am trying to accomplish is to add a checkbox to the initiation form below called Audit Report.

[image]

What I want this to do is, like I mentioned, store this info in a list or in the same list but in a column. Is this possible through Designer 2013 or is VS required? Can someone please assist?